# Unity 3D application cannot access SQL server database when built as web player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I build as a standalone executable my application works fine with database SQL server, but does not work when built as a web player. What can I do?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to connect to a database using the web player as it is inside a security sandbox.

> - Restrictions on accessing data on a domain other than the one hosting your .unity3d file.
> - Some limitation on the usage of the Sockets.

You can read more about it here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html

Comment: Excuse me could you please mention more specific what I can fix this?

Comment: You may not be able to, or not easily. Please provide more information about how you are trying to access the database.

Comment: @StevenH. I think that if you hosted the SQL server on the same domain you would be able to access it.

Comment: The way I access database is by using **System.Data.dll ** and just provide the connection string in order to connect. @yoyo

Comment: Right, and a System.Data connection won't work from a web player. You could instead access the database from the enclosing web page, and then communicate from your Unity app to the web page, as explained [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html). This will be a very different approach from System.Data usage, but I don't know if there is a better alternative.

Comment: You _might_ be able to use System.Data if you copy the DLL from Unity's install folder (i.e. the Mono version) and put it into your Assets\Plugins folder. Note that I have not tried this myself.

Comment: Yes, I used dll from installed folder of unity. And it works well after build to exe.@yoyo

Comment: Before I use unity to pass data asp.net by using browser and unity communication, but it difficult because I need to give collections of data.